# How to install balckberry app on device developed using eclipse

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

Hi am trying to install the blackberry app developed using Eclipse but its not deploying rather shows error.I dono whether am doing any wrong in code signing process can some body send some good link or some procedure to follow the deployment process.

Comment: its running fine on simulator ?

Comment: ya ya its running, am using BlackBerry 9900 simulator.

Comment: you installed 3 cod signing keys ?

Comment: i done double click on project .cod file and signature tool dialog  opened there, it stated that not signed like, there i  clicked on it and gave the Registration password, it showed signed. That is all i have done. If thee is some other steps pls kindly guide me .

Comment: **Which** error does Eclipse show? What is the message?  Please be specific in describing what you see.  Thanks.

Comment: Like .There was an error importing files.No additional Application can be found.your file might contain applications that already exists in the application list,are not compatible for device or have errors. This was the error i use to get when i deploy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly install device manager from this link : http://in.blackberry.com/services/desktop/

Secondly, when you plug in the device this Blackberry desktop software(device manager) will open.

Thirdly, on left hand side there are application tab select that and add that ".cod" file in it that will be installed on your device

try using this code, hope that what you want

Comment: Hi am Sorry for long leave.Again it stats am using the BB 9000.am not able to deploy the way like wat you posted on.It show some some exceptions.pls guide to for a solution.

Comment: what exceptions you are getting?

Comment: Like .There was an error importing files.No additional Application can be found.your file might contain applications that already exists in the application list,are not compatible for device or have errors. This was the error i use to get when i deploy.

Comment: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-install-java-application-made-in-eclipse-to-real-device/td-p/327827

Comment: Read this hope u get the solution